# Retrieve data from TableCell in its current format

Tags: javafx-2, tableview

I have a DateTime column in my TableView which is displayed in different formats as selected. I have implemented a custom cellfactory for this. Now I am trying to export the table data onto a file.

My problem is the DateTime column is coming in UTC format rather than whats displayed in the tablecell.

How can i get exact string from tablecell as they appear on screen?

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is you can't (at least, not without some ugly hacks). You presumably want to save the data for all the rows in the table, and there is no guarantee there is a TableCell for all rows in the table (in most cases, there won't be).

What you're really looking to do is to share the formatting functionality between the TableCell and the "save to file" functionality. Just refactor your cell factory so the formatting code is moved to a method somewhere, and then invoke your method when you save to file too.

E.g.

```
private String formatDateTime(DateTime dateTime) {
    // ...
}

dateTimeCol.setCellFactory(new Callback<TableColumn<MyDataType, DateTime>, TableCell<MyDateType, DateTime>>() {
    @Override
    public TableCell<MyDataType, DateTime> call(TableColumn<MyDataType, DateTime> col) {
        return new TableCell<>() {
            @Override
            public void updateItem(DateTime dateTime, boolean empty) {
                 if (empty) {
                     setText("");
                 } else {
                     setText(formatDateTime(dateTime));
                 }
            }
        };
    }
});

private void saveToFile() {
    for (MyDataType data : table.getItems()) {
         DateTime dateTime = data.getDateTime();
         String formattedDateTime = formatDateTime(dateTime);
         // output data...
    }
}
```

Comment: Yeah @James_D you are right. I got this working by changing the excel cell format to date and setting the value to java.util.Date. Apache POI coming to help.